# How can i put this javascript into the scripts folder and still work? (C# MVC 5)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is my code in C# MVC 5. I have made a partial view called _ClockPartial.cshtml that is a simple stopwatch that i am putting into the main page Index.cshtml using "@Html.Partial("_ClockPartial")".

My question is how do i separate the javascript into the scripts folder (~/Scripts/clocker.js) but still have it function properly? When i tried to separate it myself, i haven't gotten it to properly work yet. I have heard you can't do this in partial views but i'm not sure why. Even if i can't do it in partial i would still like to know how to separate the javascript into its own file and call it in one of my .cshtml views. Thanks for your help in advance!

First file is my Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Clocker</h1>
    <p class="lead">Welcome to clocker! Please sign in to start clocking your hours! Don't do too little or your hard earned cash goes into the punishiment piggy bank!</p>

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_ClockPartial")
    }
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

And this is _ClockPartial.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<h2><time>03:00:00</time></h2>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0],
                start = document.getElementById('start'),
                stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
                clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
                seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 3,
                isRunning = false,
                t;

            /* increments timer */
            function add() {
                seconds++;
                if (seconds >= 60) {
                    seconds = 0;
                    minutes++;
                    if (minutes >= 60) {
                        minutes = 0;
                        hours++;
                    }
                }

                h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

                timer();
            }

            /* decrements timer */
            function subtract() {
                seconds--;
                if (seconds < 0) {
                    seconds = 59;
                    minutes--;
                    if (minutes < 0) {
                        minutes = 59;
                        hours--;
                    }
                }

                h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

                timer();
            }
            function timer() {
                t = setTimeout(subtract, 1000);
            }
            /* enable following line to start timer automatically */
            //timer();


            /* Start button */
            start.onclick = function () {
                if (!isRunning) {
                    timer();
                    isRunning = true;
                }
            }

            /* Stop button */
            stop.onclick = function () {
                clearTimeout(t);
                isRunning = false;
            }

            /* Clear button */
            clear.onclick = function () {
                h1.textContent = "03:00:00";
                seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 3;
                isRunning = false;
            }
        });
</script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: First, you do not need to include jquery in the partial view, if it's there in index.cshtml. Then put all your script in a different file and include the reference of that file in your partial view. This should get you going

Comment: @NirbhayJha i have tried to do that, either my syntax is incorrect or something else is because i have no functionality afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new js file in the Scripts folder and add the following code of your partial view in it, let's say it's name is **clocker.js**:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0],
            start = document.getElementById('start'),
            stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
            clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
            seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 3,
            isRunning = false,
            t;

        /* increments timer */
        function add() {
            seconds++;
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
                if (minutes >= 60) {
                    minutes = 0;
                    hours++;
                }
            }

            h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

            timer();
        }

        /* decrements timer */
        function subtract() {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds < 0) {
                seconds = 59;
                minutes--;
                if (minutes < 0) {
                    minutes = 59;
                    hours--;
                }
            }

            h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

            timer();
        }
        function timer() {
            t = setTimeout(subtract, 1000);
        }
        /* enable following line to start timer automatically */
        //timer();


        /* Start button */
        start.onclick = function () {
            if (!isRunning) {
                timer();
                isRunning = true;
            }
        }

        /* Stop button */
        stop.onclick = function () {
            clearTimeout(t);
            isRunning = false;
        }

        /* Clear button */
        clear.onclick = function () {
            h1.textContent = "03:00:00";
            seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 3;
            isRunning = false;
        }
    });
```

Now modify the **BundleConfig.cs** file which is normally location in **App_Start** folder in the project and include the new js file in the bundles collection in `RegisterBundles` method after all other bundles there like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/clocker").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/clocker.js"));
```

Now in your main view after other scripts include, add include for this script as well:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/clocker")
```

and now your partial would look like:

```
<h2><time>03:00:00</time></h2>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are a saint! Thank you so much! One other quick question, why don't i have to call the javascript file function or otherwise use <script> here?

Comment: you don't need to because it is wrapped in doucment.ready function which will make sure as soon as html is loaded in the client browser the javascript within it's callback will be called automatically